# Lateral join fails on trivial example

Tags: postgresql, lateral-join

I am trying to create a timeseries and a lag of it at the same time using lateral:

```
dates as (
  SELECT generate_series(max(timestamp), min(timestamp), '1 week'::interval) as ts
  FROM batches,
  LATERAL (SELECT lag(ts) over (order by ts)) as prev_ts
),
```

For some reason I get `ERROR: column "ts" does not exist`. What is going on?

Comment: Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause. And `lag()` in a `FROM`-less query seems pointless, you could just use `NULL` literally there.

Comment: @stickybit Could you explain how to replace the lag by NULL

Comment: Just typing  `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table functions like `generate_series` belong into the `FROM` clause, since they return a table rather than a single value:

```
SELECT g.ts,
       lag(g.ts) OVER (ORDER BY g.ts) AS prev_ts
FROM (SELECT max(timestamp) AS lts, min(timestamp) AS uts
      FROM batches) AS subq
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      generate_series(lts, uts, '1 week'::interval) as g(ts);
```

You get the error not because you used `generate_series` in the `SELECT` list, which is allowed, but might have unexpected semantics, but because `ts` is defined as an alias in the `SELECT` list rather than in `FROM`. Remember that `FROM` is calculated *before* the `SELECT` list, so you cannot use aliases created in the latter in the former.

Comment: I see... could you also explain why `generate_series` cannot be used in the SELECT, or point me to an explanation.